# How to pass a nullable decimal from Mathematica to .Net via NETLink

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, wolfram-mathematica, netlink

I have no problems invoking methods with decimal parameters, as follows:

```
//public void MyMethod(decimal d){

myWrapper@MyMethod[1.23];
```

However, I need to change the signature of MyMethod as follows:

```
//public void MyMethod(decimal? d){
// this call works
myWrapper@MyMethod[Null];
```

Passing a Null to the modified MyMethod works, but passing a decimal fails:

```
myWrapper@MyMethod[1.2];
NET::methodargs: Improper arguments supplied for method named MyMethod
```

What am I missing?